# typescript can't find module for system.js alias

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular2 and when I created some aliases to modules via System.js (for example)

```
 map: {
      '%cool_modules%' : prodFolderName + '/modules',
    }
```

and when I tried to import {MyModule} from '%cool_modules%', I got an error about: typescript: can't find module %cool_modules%

The same for @angular/core , rx/Obserable erc.

Is it possible to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this kind of aliases is working with systemjs, see angular/quickstart for a good example: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js

Comment: no, these aliases  works normally) beleive me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your tsconfig.json to recognize your alias:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths": {
            "@angular/core": [
                "jspm_packages/npm/@angular/core@2.0.1"
            ],
            "rxjs/*": [
                "jspm_packages/npm/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/*"
            ],
            "systemjs": [
                "jspm_packages/npm/systemjs@0.19.38"
            ],
            "zone.js": [
                "jspm_packages/npm/zone.js@0.6.12"
            ],
            "%cool_modules%": [
                "coolModulePath"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Guilherme)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me. I add that configuration and I still have error about: can't find module in  **%sharedComponents%/datepicker/datepicker.component**.  Here is tsconfig.json   paths
**"paths": {
      "%sharedComponents%": [
        "./src/shared/components/*"
      ],
}**

.Also Webstorm is really bad work with that aliases. I have red mark about **Unresolved modules**

Comment: Probably % is not a valid character for a module name. Try "paths": { "shared-components/*": [ "./src/shared/components/*" ], }. And you need typescript 2.0 or greater to use "paths".